# Manipulate DOM asynchronously to improve performance

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I am working on a web project using html5, angularjs, jquery and websocket. I am currently testing it only on google chrome.

This starts with some base data, but the data changes via WebSockets. The problem arises when many data comes. The website experiences long delays and crashes because the website receives a lot of data in a very short period of time and then it takes time to process each data, I think. If there is any way to manipulate the `DOM` asynchronously, then each data will be processed on different threads, so the lag will not exist.

Below I have put few lines to see what I've tried:

websocket(is referential)

```
ws = new window[support]('ws://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:port/');

                    // when data is comming from the server, this method is called
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    // Here I proccess the message
    // I walk the whole message, looking at the object id
    for(.....){
       if(...){//i find the id, them i change the data
          //each materials for stundet finded
           for($x=0;$x<=evt.data[0].student[0].materials.length.....
                    $scope.data[0].students[$idfind].materials[$x]=evt.data[0].student[0].materials[$x]
          }
        }

    }
    .....
    ....
}
```

Next I show the data with angular like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="student in data[0].students">
   Name :{{studen.Name}}
   ....
   ....
   ....
   <div ng-repeat="material in student.materials">
     Material :{{material.name}}
     Calification :{{material.calification}}
    ...
    ....
   ....
   </div>

</div
```

It's only an example because each student have around 25-30 items, and each message comes around (0.3 - 1.2 seconds).

Comment: So the browser is crashing?

Comment: 30 Itens It's not this much of data. You should put a break point using the Chrome Web Tools to see what is going on!

Comment: yes i have message like it http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zuieyg&s=8#.VUzz_fl_Mko

Comment: is 30 items for each stundet, and i have around 60-150 stundets

Comment: but when the data is coming, the web is blocked, them the process end, and web back, PD:block = i can use scroll bars, buttons, and i cant write

Comment: but when i have a litle data in live (10-15 students) the web is fast